# rails custom validation for array returning undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I am writing a custom validation method for an attribute in a model called Project.  Here is my code:

```
def self.skill_options
  categories = Craft.all.collect{|craft| craft.label} #should change this later
  return categories
end

validate :validate_tag_list

def validate_tag_list
  puts skill_options.inspect.to_s
  puts 'validate tag list is happening'
  self.tag_list.each do |tag|
    if self.skill_options.include?(tag)
      puts tag.to_s + 'is included yo'
    else
          puts tag.to_s + 'not included yo'
          self.errors.add(:tag_list, "#{tag} is not a valid skill.")
    end
  end
end
```

For some reason, I am being told:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `skill_options' for #<Project:0x007fb6fc02ac28>)
```

I am not sure why this is.   I have another validation in the same model for a different attribute called category.  This validation works perfectly.  Here is the code:

```
def self.category_options
  categories = Craft.all.collect{|craft| craft.label} #should change this later
end
validates :category,  inclusion: {in: category_options}
```

The only difference is that the first validation (on skills) requires a custom validation because it is an array.

How do I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `skill_options` as `Project` class method, so you should call it this way:

```
Project.skill_options
```

because in instance method, `self` (and therefore implicit receiver) is `Project` instance instead of class. And `Project` instance doesn't have `skill_options` method defined.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby has some pretty powerful introspection you can do. You can just use `self.class` to get to the current object's class, since `skill_options` is defined as a class level method. Also, a little code cleanup as well. Sorry, couldn't help myself:

```
def self.skill_options
  Craft.pluck(:label)
end

validate :validate_tag_list

def validate_tag_list
  tag_list.each do |tag|
    unless self.class.skill_options.include?(tag)
      errors.add(:tag_list, "#{tag} is not a valid skill.")
    end
  end
end
```